# How to fix "Trailing Whitespace Violation" warnings caused by swiftlint in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftlint

How can we fix the "Trailing Whitespace Violation" warnings caused by swiftlint in my iOS project all in one go? I don't want to manually correct each one of them. Moreover, I don't want to disable these warnings so you can skip that suggestion.

I have been trying Find And Replace option but I am not getting a correct keyword to sort this out.

Image :

[image]

Comment: There’s a setting in Xcode to automatically remove trailing white space.

Comment: Something you might want to consider is switching from a reporting scanner such as SwiftLint to something that can correct issues instead of just reporting on them. I'd suggest looking at SwiftFormat.

Comment: @rmaddy, can you please tell me the path to enable this setting in Xcode?

Comment: Xcode -> Preferences -> Text Editing -> Editing -> Automatically trim trailing whitespace. And Including whitespace-only lines.

Comment: @rmaddy but it won't correct the already written lines of code but will be beneficial for  future prospects. Isn't it?

Comment: trailing_whitespace has a parameter ignores_empty_lines that enables ignoring empty lines. It didn't take all that long to remove them  but it's up to you.

Comment: For existing code if I cut and paste it fixes this violation. But if I auto format(cmd-A ctrl i) this does not work which is a bit of a pain as I like to do this a lot!

Answer (score 52):

swiftlint has an autocorrect option that will fix some issues for you, so when I get trailing whitespace warnings I run swiftlint from the command line in my project

```
$ swiftlint autocorrect
```

---

**Update**

As of version 0.43 `autocorrect` has been deprecated and replaced with `--fix` so now the command is

```
$ swiftlint --fix
```

---

`autocorrect` is still available for the time being, for more info see the [change log](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 42):

Check the 2 checkboxes in `While editing` section

[image]

Answer (score 12):

to fix *existing* (remove trailing whitespace from) whitespace-only lines, after turning on the preference include-whitespace-only-lines as rmaddy suggests, one can select all, copy the entire file, and then paste, replacing all text with the same text.  Xcode will apply the preference on the pasted code.

Comment: For existing code if I cut and paste it fixes this violation. But if I auto format the whole code file (cmd-A ctrl i) this does not work, which is a bit of a pain as I like to do this a lot!
(Xcode 13.2.1)

Answer (score 4):

if you want disable only `trailing_whitespace` then,

1. launch `Terminal` app and move to your project folder.
2. execute the command `$ ls -a` to see all the hidden files. you will see there is **.swiftlint.yml** file
3. open the file in your editor. `$ vi .swiftlint.yml` (if you installed **Sublime Text** in your mac, then use this; `$ subl .swiftlint.yml`)

Lastly, add `trailing_whitespace` in `disabled_rules`.

```
disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
  # - colon
  - comma
  # - control_statement
  - variable_name
  - force_cast
  - large_tuple
  - notification_center_detachment
  - nesting
  - function_parameter_count
  - trailing_whitespace # <---------
opt_in_rules: # some rules are only opt-in
  - empty_count

...
```

However, I recommend to use **autocorrect** rather than adding `trailing_whitespace` in the setting.

Answer (score 3):

In your build phase, I would recommend the following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
  swiftlint --fix && swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

The `swiftlint --fix` is the main component.